# "threw an exception" at the end of using in reading image from FTP

Tags: c#, image, ftp

I have a list of Image's address. With this code I can read the Image correctly :

```
List<Image> ImageList = new List<Image>();
List<string> fileNameList = new List<string>();

foreach (var fileName in fileNameList)
            {
                var request = WebRequest.Create(fileName);
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);
                using (var response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                using (var img = Image.FromStream(stream))
                {
                    img.Save(@"D:\ax.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    ImageList.Add(img);
                }
            }
```

Until this line `ImageList.Add(img);` both of the `img` and the item in `ImageList` are true. But when it's coming out of the last `using`, all of the ImageList's properties changes to "**threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentException'**"

For example for property of `Height` it changed to :

```
'((new System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView<System.Drawing.Image>(ImageList)).Items[0]).Height' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentException'
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use `using` statement for image, it will dispose image when leave the block

```
using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    var img = Image.FromStream(stream);
    img.Save(@"D:\ax.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    ImageList.Add(img);
}
```